# Trigger on Case working inconsistently creating CaseShares

Tags: apex, trigger

Wondering if there is something going on that I am missing. I have a trigger on Case that queues the creation of CaseShares for users on the related Account. For some reason this process has been working very inconsistently. When I test with a Case for a test Account, the CaseShares are created fine. But in production the CaseShares are only sometimes being created on Insert, not every time. I am forced to go in and change a related field to get them to be created. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please could you read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/332767/edit) your question to add the missing detail. For example, it would help community members if you included the Apex for the relevant parts for your trigger, details of your OWDs for sharing of Accounts and Cases, along with information about how Accounts are shared with the users or sharing groups for which you are managing the CaseShare records. There could be other information that would help so feel free to add that other useful context.

Comment: I would assume since Salesforce doesn't guarantee anywhere order of execution for Sharing records, sometimes it runs before and sometimes after AfterInsert trigger.

If someone knows where it specified I'd gladly learn it too)

Comment: Sharing memberships are computed asynchronously, but the creation of the Share record is like the creation of any other, in terms of the insertion into the database.

Comment: My main question is when those sharing memberships are computed, are the current caseshares being deleted? That's what seems to be happening but I am not entirely sure.